# Facebook Account kit Mobile number for testing

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Is there any one sandbox mobilenumber for the Facebook account kit ??

For testing Facebook account kit ?? here is the link for the facebook account kit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/

Because Apple Review team is rejecting Application due to Mobile number login

Comment: you can use firebase

Comment: i already setup facebook account kit ,  is there any problem in facebook accont kit ?

Comment: provide your code?

Comment: what is the requirement of code? ??  i just want to know is there any sandbox mobile number or not

Comment: oh hmm understand.. let's me check

Comment: Did you find a solution @MitulBhadeshiya ?

Comment: @User31 yes we need to say to apple note that we are using facebook account kit

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya I am facing same problem right now. I written that "We are using facebook account kit" but still they are rejecting app. Apple team did not receive verification sms. Please help.

Comment: @Parimal Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You Upload App In Appstore that time Write Otp Useing Facebook Account Kit In Notes of Itunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use your own phone number for Account Kit testing

Comment: dear, i don't want testing number  Apple review team is asking for that.

Comment: this works only on my phone. when i put the same number in another phone, it does not work.